# Android, remove lower status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

Im developing an android 3.0 + app.

I want to remove the status bar at the BOTTOM of the screen, the one with the android nav and time in. I've managed to remove the top bar already.

Anyone know how it's done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove the status bar at the BOTTOM of the screen, the one with the android nav and time in.

This is not supported. The user needs the system bar in order to navigate the device (e.g., press HOME).